# Display the LINQ result into Data Grid View

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, list, datagridview

I got error out of memory when i try to display the linQ result on data grid view 
Is there a limit of rows for Data Grid View ? 
 I want to dispaly 41299440

This is the error message

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException'
occurred in System.Drawing.dll
```

this is the linQ code

```
var sets =
    from a in patient
    from b in patient
    from c in patient
    from d in patient
    from l in patient
    where a.VisitNum < b.VisitNum 
          && b.VisitNum < c.VisitNum 
          && c.VisitNum < d.VisitNum 
          && d.VisitNum < l.VisitNum

    select new { a, b, c, d, l };
```

and this how i display the result

```
object[] buffer = new object[5];
List<DataGridViewRow> rows = new List<DataGridViewRow>();
foreach (var custObj in sets)
{
    buffer[0] = custObj.a.VisitNum;
    buffer[1] = custObj.a.ID;
    buffer[2] = patientname;
    buffer[3] = custObj.a.date;
    buffer[4] = description(Convert.ToInt32(custObj.a.RaId));
    rows.Add(new DataGridViewRow());
    rows[rows.Count - 1].CreateCells(dataGridView1, buffer);

    buffer[0] = custObj.b.VisitNum;
    buffer[1] = custObj.b.ID;
    buffer[2] = patientname;
    buffer[3] = custObj.b.date;
    buffer[4] = description(Convert.ToInt32(custObj.b.RaId));
    rows.Add(new DataGridViewRow());
    rows[rows.Count - 1].CreateCells(dataGridView1, buffer);

    buffer[0] = custObj.c.VisitNum;
    buffer[1] = custObj.c.ID;
    buffer[2] = patientname;
    buffer[3] = custObj.c.date;
    buffer[4] = description(Convert.ToInt32(custObj.c.RaId));
    rows.Add(new DataGridViewRow());
    rows[rows.Count - 1].CreateCells(dataGridView1, buffer);

    buffer[0] = custObj.d.VisitNum;
    buffer[1] = custObj.d.ID;
    buffer[2] = patientname;
    buffer[3] = custObj.d.date;
    buffer[4] = description(Convert.ToInt32(custObj.d.RaId));
    rows.Add(new DataGridViewRow());
    rows[rows.Count - 1].CreateCells(dataGridView1, buffer);

    buffer[0] = custObj.l.VisitNum;
    buffer[1] = custObj.l.ID;
    buffer[2] = patientname;
    buffer[3] = custObj.l.date;
    buffer[4] = description(Convert.ToInt32(custObj.l.RaId));
    rows.Add(new DataGridViewRow());
    rows[rows.Count - 1].CreateCells(dataGridView1, buffer);
    rows.Add(new DataGridViewRow());                           
}
dataGridView1.Rows.AddRange(rows.ToArray());
```

any suggestions?

Comment: So you are willing to display a DataGridView containing over 41 million rows? Are you serious?

Comment: 41 million rows is insane. I suggest you include filter parameters in your form.

Comment: How much the maximum limit for Datagridview to display ?

Comment: @Wimaxmax - The maximum limit for Datagridview will be dependent on the amount of memory you have, but that isn't the point. A grid with 4 million rows isn't usable by anyone. No one is going to find anything in that amount of data. You need to be thinking about how to filter the data before putting it in the DataGridView.